# Does AdMob know if an ad is not visible?

Tags: ios, admob

I am implementing AdMob into my app. My banner is inside a `UIView` that is set to alpha 0.0. When the user wants to search, it fades in.

Does Google Ad Services know whether the ad is hidden and would it count as an impression? I don’t want to break any rules but I can’t find any info about this.

Comment: i imagine they would have code in their SDK to detect this because otherwise you could put loads of ads on the page and not show any

Comment: @Scriptable Yes that Is what I assumed, the root view of the banner is the view that holds the search view, and the banner sits on the searchView that is hidden and sits on top of the root view until the user opens it. So I think technically the banner is loaded when the root view is, but hopefully, there is something in the SDK that knows that the banner is not visible yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had any problems so far, and it seems that there is code implemented to detect this. So an ad on a hidden view should not cause any problems with the AdMob account as it won't count impressions while hidden.